# WKWebView removes automatically filled in data

Tags: swift, macos, wkwebview

I try to automatically fill in a [login formula](https://lobby.ogame.gameforge.com/de_DE/) and confirm data by clicking the login button. I would like to use Swift 5, macOS 10.15 and a WKWebView.

The first step is done, I can fill in my login data like this:

```
import Cocoa
import WebKit

class ViewController: NSViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {
    let webView = WKWebView()
    let button = NSButton()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        button.frame = CGRect(x: 400, y: 0, width: 40, height: 20)
        button.image = NSImage(named: NSImage.Name("Button"))
        button.target = self
        button.action = #selector(self.fillIn)
        self.view.addSubview(button)

        self.webView.uiDelegate = self
        self.webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 270)
        view.addSubview(webView)
        let url = URL(string: "https://lobby.ogame.gameforge.com/de_DE/hub")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        webView.load(request)
    }

    @objc func fillIn() {
        setWebViewValue(name: "email", data: "user@web.de")
        setWebViewValue(name: "password", data: "pwdpwd")
    }

    func setWebViewValue(name: String, data: String) {
        let jsFunc = "document.getElementsByName(\"\(name)\")[0].value = \"\(data)\""
        webView.evaluateJavaScript(jsFunc) {(result, error) in
            print(result, error)
        }
    }
}
```

But when I click the login button, all data will be removed. So the *email* and *password* input fields are empty while logging in and I get an invalid input data error.

**Example**

[image: Example gif]

Please note, even if the email address is wrong, the address and password input fields are not cleared when clicking to the login button.

**Question:**

Why is the auto-filled data deleted when you click the login button and why is the data that was entered normally not deleted?

Answer (score -1):

Check the javascript code on the page to see if it is clearing the fields on it's own or maybe it was waiting for typing into the fields.